# load data to server using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

I have read a lot about loading or posting data to server via jquery, but can`t find the right one for me. I have a bunch of inputs and data obtained from them I contain in a list (array).

I need to load it to server. I think I should do it like this

client side

```
<html>
<head>
<title>the title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#driver").click(function(event){
      var name = $("#name").val();
      $("#stage").load('/jquery/result.php', {"name":name} );
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Enter your name and click on the button:</p>
    <input type="input" id="name" size="40" /><br />
    <div id="stage" style="background-color:blue;">
         STAGE
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="driver" value="Show Result" />
</body>
</html>
```

server side

```
<?php
if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
{
   $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
   echo "Welcome ". $name;
}
?>
```

got it from here [passing data to server](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm) but in my case I need to load a list (array) and I have no idea how the php part must be written in python at server side. Also need to mention that I`m using Flask.

I will really appreciate any help.

**EDIT**

Well, I`m almost there!

Except of a strange thing that happens

home.html

```
<script>
var dict = {}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#save").click(function(){
        var ids = []
        var datas = []
        $(".result").each(function() {
            ids.push(this.id);
            datas.push(this.value);
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
            dict[ids[i]] = datas[i];
        }
        console.log(ids);
        console.log(datas)

    });
});

var bla = {1:'4', 2:'5', 3:'6', 4:'7', 5:'4', 6:'5', 7:'6', 8:'7'}

console.log(dict)

$(function() {
    $('a#calculate').bind('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('/add_numbers', dict, function(data) {
            $("#result").text(data.result);
        });
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
      <p><input type=text size=5 name=a> +
         <input type=text size=5 name=b> =
         <span id=result>?</span>
     <p><a href=# id=calculate>calculate server side</a>

     <div id="chosen">
            {% for key, value in selected.iteritems() %}
                    {{value[0]}}<input type="text" id="{{key}}" size="5" class="result">{{value[1]}}<br>
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" id="save" value="save">
    </div>
```

views.py

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_work():
    demount = DemountForm(request.form)
    tile = TileForm(request.form)
    chosen = []
    for each in session['data']:
        chosen.append(each)
    selected = methods.get_selected(chosen)
    return render_template('home.html', demount=demount, tile=tile, selected = selected)

@app.route('/add_numbers')
def add_numbers():
    a = request.args.get('1', '0', type=str)
    return jsonify(result=a)
```

I got solution from [flask "ajax with jquery"](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/).

**BUT**, here is a problem.

In case I use that strange variable `bla` in template `$.getJSON('/add_numbers', bla, function(data)` it works just fine. It works because data in `bla` is global and it is seen in getJSON and this function send data to `/add_number`, add to URL data from `bla` like so: `"http://localhost:5000/add_numbers?1=4&2=5&3=6&4=7&5=4&6=5&7=6&8=7"`and then result comes back with `return jsonify(result=a)`.

The problem comes when I use `dict` in `$.getJSON('/add_numbers', dict, function(data)`.

After the previous function, where dict is formed `$(document).ready(function(){ $("#save").click(function(){...` data from `dict` is added to current URL like this:`http://localhost:5000/home?1=6&2=6&3=6&4=6&5=6&6=6` and variable `dict` does not contain data anymore.

As far as I understand this happens due to, let`s say, URLs, to which each function is related.

Does anyone know how this problem can be solved?

Comment: specific reason to for jquery 132.

Comment: you mean why I use jquery?

Comment: That is an ancient version of jQuery. http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: I didn`t mean I will use this version, I meant the way it is done

Comment: Do you want to send data to the server or get data from the server? You're asking for "load data to server", and the given code uses load(), which gets data from the server ?

Comment: Also, just sticking your form elements inside a form would make this a lot easier, as you could use serialize().

Comment: Probably I misunderstood(((. I`m new to jquery. I need to load data from page to server.

Comment: The AJAX API options have evolved in jQuery. Get a recent version for the best support.

Answer (score 2):

normally data is passed to the server with ajax this is an example that could work.

```
      $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: '/jquery/result.php',
          data: {"name":$('#name').val()},
          success: function(data){
            //maybe do something with response (data)
          }
        });
```

Getting this info on server side goes like this

```
<?PHP $name = $_POST['name']; ?>
```

after that u can use the name variable whatever way u like

Comment: any ideas how the code at server side for accepting this data might look like?

Comment: @Julia i added server side to my answer

Comment: oh i'm sorry i thought u needed the php server side code... i'm sorry but i don't know phyton yet

Answer (score 0):

In Flask, you can do something like that

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json
import random

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    return """<html>
                   <head>
                      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
                      <script>
                           $(document).ready(function(){

                                $('#btnSend').click(function(){

                                    var  fruits = ["apple", "banana", "orange"];

                                    $.ajax({
                                      type: 'POST',
                                      url: '/do_something',
                                      data: {"fruits":JSON.stringify(fruits)},
                                      success: function(data){
                                        alert(data);
                                      }
                                    });
                                });

                           });
                      </script>
                   </head>
                   <body>
                    <input type="button" id="btnSend" value="send fruits">
                    </body>
                   </html>"""


@app.route('/do_something', methods=['POST'])
def view_do_something():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        fruits = json.loads(request.form.get("fruits"))
        fruit = fruits[random.randint(0, len(fruits))]
        return fruit
    else:
        return "no fruit"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Run script and try

Comment: thanks, it does work, but what if I need to send a {key:value, key:value, key:value} and at server obtain all of them?

Comment: Hm, its strange, with 'fruits = json.loads(request.form.get("fruits"))' I actually get the whole list, but I can`t pass it as to other function. I got 'POST localhost:5000/do_something 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is what I came up with.

home.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#calculate').bind('click', function() {
             var dict = {}
         var ids = []
         var datas = []
         $(".result").each(function() {
            ids.push(this.id);
            datas.push(this.value);
         });

         for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
            dict[ids[i]] = datas[i];
         }

         console.log(ids);
         console.log(datas)
         console.log(dict)

         $.getJSON('/add_numbers', dict, function(data) {
            $("#result").text(data.result);
         });
         return false;
      });
});
</script>
```

view.py

```
import methods

@app.route('/add_numbers')
def add_numbers():
    ident = []
    amount = []
    ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    for each in ids:
        val = request.args.get(str(each), '0', type=str)
        if int(val) != 0:
            ident.append(each)
            amount.append(int(val))
    res = methods.calc(ident, amount)
    return jsonify(result=res)
```

methods.py

```
def calc(ids, amount):
    prices = db_session.query(Work.price).filter(Work.id.in_((ids))).all()
    prices = [each[0] for each in prices] 
    i = 0
    result = 0
    while i < len(ids):
        result += prices[i]*amount[i]
        i += 1
    return result
```

**It works!** 
Thanks to everyone.